# Protect iOS app from runtime hooking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak, objective-c-runtime

iOS application when running in a device gets attached to many runtime libraries. How can we protect our iOS app from any other debugger getting attacked to the application process. 
Like using GDB we can hack into the application process and manipulate runtime. Is there a way we can stop in using any setting or code?
Or is there a way to check if any other runtime libraries are getting attached to the process?
Can we quite the app in such scenarios?

Comment: The answer is a profound no. Even if you could somehow manage to do that, all it takes is someone stripping/replacing the relevant part of the binary on disk to remove any countermeasures you may have.

You have to have some level of trust in the operating system on iOS, that's the entire basis of the 'walled garden' ecosystem.

If someone malicious has root access to the device, all bets are off - you don't control it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your response @RichardJ.RossIII. Is there a way to at least protect the binary from being resigned by some other party?

Comment: @DebasishChowdhury Your program is an array of bytes. You cannot protect an array of bytes from being modified.

Answer (score 0):

We can check the modification date of the Info.plist file and Appname and compare it with the package modified date. If there is a miss match found we can conclude that the app binary was modified.

```
//Check date of modifications in files (if different - app cracked)
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Info.plist", bundlePath];
NSString* path2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/AppName", bundlePath];
NSDate* infoModifiedDate = [[manager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:path error:nil] fileModificationDate];
NSDate* infoModifiedDate2 = [[manager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:path2 error:nil]  fileModificationDate];
NSDate* pkgInfoModifiedDate = [[manager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PkgInfo"] error:nil] fileModificationDate];
if([infoModifiedDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] > [pkgInfoModifiedDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]) {
    return YES;
}
if([infoModifiedDate2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] > [pkgInfoModifiedDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]) {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If the app binary was modified, that code may no longer be there.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, hope it helps somebody. In case you like pure, Swift solution, you might want to look at [iOSSecuritySuite](https://github.com/securing/IOSSecuritySuite). It provides some protections against modifications you mentioned, for instance debugging detection:

```swift
let amIDebugged: Bool = IOSSecuritySuite.amIDebugged()
```

Which might save you some lines if you'd wanted to write it on your own.